# How is Dulac's Multiplier selected?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, systems-of-equations, nonlinear-system, periodic-functions

I'm aware that Dulac's (Negative) Criterion states that a system of differential equations of the form $x' = f(x,y), \; y' = g(x,y)$ has no periodic orbits in the plane if we can find some function $\varphi (x,y)$ such that the expression
$$
\frac{\partial (f \varphi)}{\partial x} + \frac{\partial (g \varphi)}{\partial y}
$$
has the same sign for all $x, \; y$ in the domain.

My question is, how is the function $\varphi (x, \; y)$ (Dulac's Multiplier) found?

I the solutions to the questions given out in lectures, this usually takes values
$$
\frac{1}{xy} \quad \text{or} \quad x^{n}
$$
where $n$ is some parameter to be found. Can $\varphi$ take any other values?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, according to the [theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bendixson%E2%80%93Dulac_theorem), $\varphi(x,y)$ can be any continuously differentiable function. There is no general method to find suitable $\varphi(x,y)$, given two functions $f$ and $g$. Usually, you'll get an idea about a $\varphi(x,y)$ that might work when looking at the PDE $\frac{\partial (f \varphi)}{\partial x} + \frac{\partial (g \varphi)}{\partial y}$. Note that you can only hope to find such a function if the planar system has no periodic orbits; therefore, if you fail to find a suitable $\varphi(x,y)$, that could also mean that the system at hand does possess a periodic orbit somewhere.

So, to conclude, if you're able to find such a $\varphi(x,y)$ for a given planar system, that's good, but it's often a matter of chance. A bit similar to the [Lyapunov function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lyapunov_function).